# Unknown timestamp format output by Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, timestamp

I'm querying to Oplog using mongoose in node.js, to get the timestamp of the last oplog record using the following code:

```
oplogModel.find().sort('-ts').limit(1).select('ts').exec(function(err, res){
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    lastTimestamp=res[0];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(lastTimestamp));
});
```

But the output I'm getting is `{"ts":"6260013777081597954"}`

When I run this in mongo shell,

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find({}, {ts:1, _id:0}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1);
```

I get : `{ "ts" : Timestamp(1457523037, 2) }`

How can  I convert `{"ts":"6260013777081597954"}` to epoch time or iso time?
What format is this timestamp in?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) should help here.

Comment: There is something going wrong here. Converting the timestamp you get in Mongo to an integer using the [`bson-timestamp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-timestamp) library gives a completely different result

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting is because of the line `console.log(JSON.stringify(lastTimestamp))` since `JSON.stringify(lastTimestamp)` parses the resulting object to string.

In essence you need to convert the timestamp to a 32-bit int:

```
oplogModel.find().sort('-ts').limit(1).select('ts').exec(function(err, res){
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    lastTimestamp=res[0].ts;
    console.log(lastTimestamp); // 6260013777081597954

    var h = 4294967296, // 2^32
        timestamp = Math.floor(lastTimestamp / 4294967296), // convert to 32-bit int
        date = new Date(timestamp * 1000); // Date() expects milliseconds.

    console.log(date);
});
```

When you get `{ "ts" : Timestamp(1457523037, 2) }` in mongo shell, the first parameter represents a 32-bit value indicating seconds since the unix epoch and the second parameter is 32-bit ordinal value is for ordering operations occuring in the same second.

For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) but keep in mind that the BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use and in your own data you should prefer the Date type.

Comment: I'm querying oplog which is an internal read-only collection, hence I cannot choose it's datetime.